# Releasing a mutex created on startup within the same application

Tags: delphi

I create a mutex at the start of the my application, primarily to prevent running 2 instances of same application.

```
  if CreateMutex(nil,false,'Proton Studio') = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then exit;
```

However, when I reconfigure my application I need to release the mutex before the application is closed in order to start a short program which will then restart my application.

```
  hw := OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, false, 'Proton Studio');
  if ReleaseMutex(hw)then begin
    if ShellExecute(application.Handle, 'open',
    Pchar('StudioRestart.exe'), PChar(Application.ExeName),'', SW_SHOWNORMAL) > 32 then
      fmIDEMain.Close
    else
      ShowMessage('Unable to Restart, please close and restart manually')
  end
```

OpenMutex returns a handle but when I call ReleaseMutex the function returns false.  How should I close this mutex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use the *existence* of the mutex as the criterion to decide whether the process already runs and not who *owns* the mutex. `ReleaseMutex` is used to give up ownership of a mutex if you currently own it. But your code doesn't actually retrieve ownership of the mutex anywhere.

I see these ways towards solving your problem:

1. Destroy mutex instead of trying to release it.

Instead of using `ReleaseMutex`, use `CloseHandle` to destroy the mutex. If you are the only one holding a handle to the mutex, it will be gone afterwards.

For this purpose, remember the original handle returned by `CreateMutex` and don't open the mutex a second time.

2. Use mutexes as intended

Instead of using the mere existing of the mutex, try to obtain ownership by calling `WaitForSingleObject` on it. You can then release it by calling `ReleaseMutex`.

3. External program should wait (my preferred method)

Have the external program wait until the old instance of the application was fully terminated before trying to start a new instance.